# Can I Construct a complete soap message using mule message enricher?

Tags: wso2, mule, esb, wso2-esb

Using wso2 esb i can construct a complete soap message like this:

```
<enrich>
    <source type="inline" clone="true">
       <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">                                                           
          <m0:request>                                                                        
             <m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol>                                                            
          </m0:request>                                            
       </m0:getQuote>
    </source>
    <target type="body" />
 </enrich>
```

I've read http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Message+Enricher

```
  <enricher target="#[variable:state]">
       <outbound-endpoint ref="stateLookup"/>
     </enricher>
```

I want to know how to configure to ref a inline payload or a jaxb object. 
Can I ref a custom component which return a jaxb object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the current message payload with a new payload coming from the result of a custom component, then just use a **component** not an **enricher**.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is something similar to below.

```
<enrich>
       <source [clone=true|false] [type=custom|envelope|body|property|inline] xpath="" property="" />
       <target [action=replace|child|sibiling] [type=custom|envelope|body|property|inline] xpath="" property="" />
 </enrich>
```

This http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.2/docs/mediators/enrich.html will guide you further.

--
Thilini